# Store values inside array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have multiple inputs, for example:

```
<input id=xxx_1>
<input id=xxx_2>
```

I want the values from input to be stored inside an array. At the moment what I have is this but it doesn't work. I have tried to Google it and I can't find any solution. I can't understand why this does not work.

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i >= 14; i++) {
  array[i] = $(this).find("#xxx_" + i + "").val();
}
```

What I what is to have an array like this:

```
[ value, value, value,... ]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: `$(this)..find(...` should be `$(this).find(...`. Also note that you can make this much simpler by removing the incremental `id` attributes, putting a common class on all those elements and using `map()`

Comment: that is corret in my code was a misspelling, Thanks in same

Comment: So does that mean it's working now?

Comment: No it is not workin as i said in my code that is correct what just a misspelling the  extra "."

Comment: Replace `>=` with `<=`.

Comment: Oh my good i am soo noob thanks working 6h straight :S thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparison operator in your for loop is the wrong way round, and so your code never enters it.

You probably want to look for when i is *less than* or equal to 14, using <= .

```
var array = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
  array[i] = $(this).find("#xxx_" + i + "").val();
}
```

Comment: Your code still aren't storing values inside array

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`attributs starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select all elements who `id` starts with `xxx`, then you can iterate over these elements using [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```js
var array = [];
$( "[id^='xxx']" ).each(function() {
  array.push(this.value);
});

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="xxx_1" value="123">
<input id="xxx_2" value="456">
```